# How to detect the view touch outside dragging?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I'm trying to code an imageView click feedback using the onTouch method. My code is used to scale the imageView when pressed(`MotionEvet.ACTION_DOWN`) and return to its normal size when the user stop pressing(`MotionEvet.ACTION_UP`). But what I'm not able to code is the action when the user drags its finger out of the imageView.

I've seen a solution which tells to use `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` at the beginning of the switch statement, but this doesn't work for me.

My code is the next one:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        switch (action) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        clickOutTransformation(ico);
        return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        clickOutTransformation(ico);

         switch (i) {
            case 1:
            fondoApp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_blue_bubbles_lite);
            i++;
            break;
            case 2:
            fondoApp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_espectrum);
            i++;
            break;
            case 3:
            fondoApp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_black_and_violet);
            i++;
            break;
            case 4:
            fondoApp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_green);
            i++;
            break;
            case 5:
            fondoApp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_blur_blue_ed);
            i = 1;
            break;

            default:
            break;
            }
            return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            clickInTransformation(ico);
            return true;

            default:
            break;

            }
             return false;

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get it with this solution:

```
private Rect rect;    // Variable rect to hold the bounds of the view

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (!rect.contains(v.getLeft() + (int) event.getX(), v.getTop() + (int) event.getY())) {
                // User moved outside bounds
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            rect = new Rect(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use if case: MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN for scaling and case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: for scaling down to normal size ...

ACTION_DOWN fires, when you touch you screen and ACTION_UP fires, when you take off you finger from view

Comment: That's the way it's programmed... What do you mean?

Comment: That runs good but what I want is to detect the movement out of the view and MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE reacts on any finger movement, even inside of the view